# Weblogic - How to add specific jar to load in weblogic without affecting other

Tags: weblogic, jodatime

I want to use joda-time version 1.6 in my weblogic application, weblogic comes with joda-time 1.2 by default, i want the server to load for the newest joda-time library.

My joda-time jar located at:

```
/WEB-INF/lib/
```

It works by modifying /WEB-INF/weblogic.xml with the following:

```
<container-descriptor>     
<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>   
</container-descriptor>
```

But, there is a problem if i add the above codes, it will affect my other functions that use other libraries.

How can i just want weblogic to use the latest joda-time without affecting other libraries?

I tried to modify weblogic-application.xml in /META-INF/, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead add the following to only overwrite the jodatime library

```
 <wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.joda.time</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
 </wls:container-descriptor>
```

Comment: i tried this too, add this specific line to override the jodatime library but it don't work, still affecting others, don't know why

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Maybe add the sideeffects to your original posts? Like which libraries or what behaviour is negatively effected by overriding joda-time. That might shed some light on it

Comment: do you want that some classes from the same war file use one version of joda, and the rest use a different version ?
all these classes and joda are in the same war classpath ? (WEB-INF/lib)
If this is the situation then there is no solution because all belong to the same classloader.